# Active characters inside commands

Tags: catcodes, tipa

I'm trying to ease my typesetting of phonetics with `tipa` by creating a custom command `myipa` which is supposed to substitute some common characters for the corresponding `tipa`codes. A much simplified example follows below, which replaces all `a`s with `@`s (which is the `tipa` code for a schwa):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}

\newcommand*\mytransform[1]{
  \begingroup%
      \catcode`\a=\active%
      \def a{@}%
      #1%
  \endgroup%
}

\newcommand*\myipa[1]{\textipa{\mytransform{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\myipa{blabla}

\end{document}
```

However, all I get is `Missing control sequence inserted \myipa{blabla}`. This is my first time experimenting with active characters, so there is a high probability that I have completely misunderstood some important central idea, so feel free to fill me in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using active characters is not recommended for this application: you lose the possibility of having any control sequence with an `a` in its name inside the argument of `\myipa`.

How could you do it? Here's what's necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}

\newcommand\myipa{%
  \begingroup\catcode`\a=\active
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`a
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{@}%
  \innermyipa
}
\newcommand*{\innermyipa}[1]{\textipa{#1}\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\myipa{blabla}

\end{document}
```

The definition of `a` as active character has to be done indirectly; there are other ways, but this one is good because it sets the meaning of the active `a` only locally. The most important thing is not to absorb the argument before activating the character.

The disadvantage is that `\myipa` can't be used in the argument of another command, so `\section{Here is \myipa{blabla}}` would die horribly.

A different approach is to do a string substitution. You can use the `xstring` package or `expl3` with `xparse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myipa}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \textipa{ #2 } }
   { \gaussler_myipa:n { #2 } }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__gaussler_input_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \gaussler_myipa:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__gaussler_input_tl { #1 }
  % change each `a' into `@'
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__gaussler_input_tl { a } { @ }
  \textipa{ \l__gaussler_input_tl }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Here is \myipa{blabla}}

\myipa{blabla}

\myipa*{blabla}
\end{document}
```

This command can be used in arguments; I also added a *-variant that doesn't do any substitution.

[image]