# Trouble defining a macro that typesets underscore characters as _

Tags: macros, catcodes

I want to define a macro that typesets its argument in typewriter font and 
allows for underscore characters in its argument. Within a group, I make `_` active, I define `\_` to be typeset as an underscore, and then I insert the text.

This approach works great *outside* the definition of my macro, but TeX complains about two `Missing $ inserted` if I attempt to pass some text containing underscore characters as argument to the macro in question. What's going on?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\allowsforunderscores[1]%
{%
    \begingroup
        \ttfamily
        \catcode`\_=\active                     
        \let\_\textunderscore%
        #1%
    \endgroup
}   

\begin{document}

%\allowsforunderscores{Bertrand_Russell}    % if uncommented, this generates an error

% However, the following compiles just fine.
{
    \ttfamily
    \catcode`\_=\active                     
    \let\_\textunderscore
    Bertrand_Russell%
}
\( 4_4 \) % sanity check

\end{document}
```

Comment: The underscore is not active when you do the definition.

Comment: @egreg Do you mean that the macro parses its the argument before making `_` active?

Comment: No; but TeX absorbs tokens and catcode assignments are permanent (unless `\scantokens` is used).

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125572/active-characters-inside-commands

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three errors in your strategy.

First error: `\let\_=\textunderscore` doesn't do anything to the active `_`.

Second error: even if you type `\let_=\textunderscore` this wouldn't work, because `_` is not active at the moment the definition is performed, so the token `_` still has category code 12 and `\let_=\textunderscore` will be illegal at macro call. Note that you *can* use `\_` to mean the character code of the underscore in a context like

```
\catcode`\_=\active
```

but this doesn't mean you can use `\let\_=...` for giving a meaning to the active underscore.

Third error: you can't change the category code of tokens in an already absorbed argument unless you use `\scantokens`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%% A macro used in both strategies
%% At definition time the token `_` must be active
\begingroup
\catcode`_=\active
\gdef\activate@us{%
  \let_\textunderscore
  \catcode`\_=\active
}
\endgroup
%%% Alternative definition of \activate@us not requiring \gdef
%\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_
%\lowercase{\endgroup
%  \def\activate@us{\let~\textunderscore\catcode`\_=\active}}


% First strategy
\newcommand{\allowforunderscoresA}{%
  \begingroup
  \activate@us
  \@allowforunderscores
}
\newcommand{\@allowforunderscores}[1]{%
   \ttfamily
   #1%
    \endgroup
}   

% Second strategy
\newcommand{\allowforunderscoresB}[1]{%
  \begingroup\activate@us\ttfamily
  \scantokens{#1\endinput}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

X\allowforunderscoresA{Bertrand_Russell}X

X\allowforunderscoresB{Bertrand_Russell}X%
\footnote{\allowforunderscoresB{Bertrand_Russell}}

\end{document}
```

Note that the first macro cannot appear in the argument to another command, while `\allowforunderscoresB` can.

[image]

Comment: What does it mean when you say *is not active*? What is activation?

Comment: @Sigur See chapter 7 of the TeXbook. *Activation*, here, means make a character active, i.e. assign it a a catcode of 13. An active character then behaves almost like any other control sequence. `~` is an active character by default.

Comment: @Jubobs `\gdef` is required because the definition has to be given in a context where `_` is active; using a group doesn't require knowing what its catcode is outside the group. There are other ways, I added one.

Comment: A very late follow-up question (only if you have time): is there a specific reason why you use `\begingroup ... \endgroup` instead of `\bgroup ... \egroup`, here?

Comment: @Jubobs Just personal preference. It usually doesn't make a difference when just grouping is involved; however this isn't true in math mode, where `\bgroup...\egroup` and `\begingroup...\endgroup` behave differently.

Answer (score 3):

What is passed to the macro is not a sequence of characters but a sequence of tokens. Catcode changes have no effect in tokens, they only change the mapping that is used when generating tokens from characters. This is exactly why you can not use `\verb` in a macro argument.

Simplest solution is to use `url` package and `\url{Bertrand_Russell}` (which uses math mode rather than catcode changes to do its work, or you can re-tokenise the argument using `\scantokens` after changing the catcodes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but isn't loading a whole package for such a simple thing a bit overkill?

Comment: @Jubobs no. If you do it as well with less tex code than is in url.sty then you be doing well:-)

Answer (score 1):

> [image: underscore]

But `\allowsforunderscores` can not be used inside the argument of another macro. It can be used with no problem in some environments. Except those nasty ones which gather their contents (they are rare).

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`_ 13
\newcommand\allowsforunderscores
{%
    \bgroup
        \ttfamily
        \let_\textunderscore
        \catcode`\_=\active                
    \let\next=%
}%
\catcode`_ 8

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\allowsforunderscores{Bertrand_Russell}  

Hello $H_{ij}$ 

\end{document}
```