# What is Algorithm2e's problem with the letter Q?

Tags: algorithm2e

No, seriously.

The following LaTeX document is typeset with no issues:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \Begin(F){
        }
    \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to focus on the `\Begin(F)` line. Here are the results of my experiments:

1. If I replace it with `\Begin(Q)`, there are no problems.
2. If I replace it with `\Begin([x])`, there are still no problems.
3. If I replace it with `\Begin([Q])`, however, weird things happen. I end up with an algorithm starting with `beginQ [Q]`, as in this screenshot:

   [image: A very strange algorithm indeed]
4. If I replace it with `\Begin($[Q]$)`, pdflatex starts complaining and doesn't know how to typeset the document.
5. If I replace it with `\Begin($[x,Q]$)` pdflatex still fails.
6. If I replace it with `\Begin($[Q,x,r]$)`, pdflatex produces an algorithm starting with `beginx [Q,x,r]`.

None of these issues arise if I use a letter other than Q. What on earth is happening?

Edit: I use TeX Live 2013 and the lastest version (2013/01/06 v5.00) of `algorithm2e`.

Comment: Qriouser and Qriouser... Could you edit your question to add a screenshot of the output?

Comment: @Jubobs, there you go.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I just had a look at the [`algorithm2e` source code](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/tex/algorithm2e.sty). The behaviour you report can be traced to the definition of a macro called `\ifArgumentEmpty` (defined in `algorithm2e.sty`), which changes (or, rather, [*attempts* to change](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178964/21891)) the catcode of the uppercase letter `Q`:

```
\long\def\ifArgumentEmpty#1{\bgroup
    \catcode`\Q=3
    \catcode`\T=3
    \long\def\@tempa##1##2Q##3##4##5T{##4}%
    \xdef\@tempa{\@tempa#1QQ{\noexpand\@secondoftwo}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}T}%
\egroup\@tempa}
```

If you change the definition of that macro by replacing all instances of `Q` by another character (`A` in my code below), the problem will then occur with that other character but no longer with the letter Q.

[image]

I'm not familiar enough with the `algorithm2e` source code to come up with anything better than this explanation. You should probably get in touch with the maintainer about this issue with Q.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifArgumentEmpty#1{\bgroup
    \catcode`\A=3
    \catcode`\B=3
    \long\def\@tempa##1##2A##3##4##5B{##4}%
    \xdef\@tempa{\@tempa#1AA{\noexpand\@secondoftwo}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}B}%
\egroup\@tempa}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \Begin([A]){
        }
    \end{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \Begin([Q]){
        }
    \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 34):

As Jubobs correctly diagnosed, the problem is in `\ifArgumentEmpty`. Credits for pinpointing the issue should go to him. Here's an analysis of the problem and a couple of workarounds.

Let's see what `\ifArgumentEmpty` should do, at least in the intentions of the package author. The argument is absorbed and a temporary macro is defined:

```
\long\def\@tempa#1#2Q#3#4#5T{#4}
```

The `#` becomes `##` because we're in a definition. Then the argument to `\ifArgumentEmpty` is passed to

```
\xdef\@tempa{\@tempa#1QQ{\noexpand\@secondoftwo}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}T}
```

Note that `#1` will be what's inside the pair of parentheses when `\Begin` is involved. So, let's see the case when the argument is empty or just spaces (spaces will be ignored because the first argument to `\@tempa` is undelimited).

If `#1` is empty, TeX sees

```
\@tempa QQ{\noexpand\@secondoftwo}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}T
```

so the first argument to `\@tempa` is `Q`, the second argument is empty, the third argument is `\noexpand\@secondoftwo` and the fourth argument is `\noexpand\@firstoftwo`; the fifth argument is empty.

If `#1` is nonempty, its first token is the first argument to `\@tempa`, the (possibly zero) remaining tokens are the second argument, the third argument is `Q`, the fourth argument is `\noexpand\@secondoftwo` and the fifth one is `\noexpand\@firstoftwo`.

So `\@tempa` is expanded, leaving `\noexpand\@firstoftwo` in the empty case, `\noexpand\@secondoftwo` in the nonempty case.

This in theory; the change of the category code of `Q` and `T` should ensure that these tokens are not contained in the argument to `\ifArgumentEmpty`. But in this code they ***don't*** have category code 3 as the programmer thinks. The category code is fixed at the moment of the definition and when the macro is defined the two tokens are letters. The instructions `` \catcode`Q=3 `` and `` \catcode`T=3 `` simply do nothing.

Let's see what happens when the argument is `[Q]`: TeX sees

```
\@tempa [Q]QQ{\noexpand\@secondoftwo}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}T
```

The first argument to `\@tempa` is `[`; the second argument is empty, the third argument is `]`, the fourth argument is `Q` and the fifth argument is all that remains up to `T`. Thus `\@tempa` is defined to be `Q` and the second and third (apparent) arguments to `\ifArgumentEmpty` also remain in the input stream, because there's no `\@firstoftwo` or `\@secondoftwo` that takes care of them.

The same problem arises whenever the *second* token of the argument to `\ifArgumentEmpty` is `Q`.

Here's a correct definition:

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`\Q=3
\catcode`\T=3
\long\gdef\ifArgumentEmpty#1{%      
  \long\def\@tempa##1##2Q##3##4##5T{##4}%
  \edef\@tempa{\@tempa#1QQ{\noexpand\@secondoftwo}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}T}%
  \@tempa
}
\endgroup
\makeatother
```

There's no need of a group inside the macro, nor of `\xdef`.

Note that we have to use `\gdef` for defining `\ifArgumentEmpty`, in order to localize the change in category codes.

Test example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Original definition}

Empty: \ifArgumentEmpty{}{Empty}{Non empty}

Spaces: \ifArgumentEmpty{ }{Empty}{Non empty}

ABC: \ifArgumentEmpty{ABC}{Empty}{Non empty}

Q: \ifArgumentEmpty{Q}{Empty}{Non empty}

[Q]: \ifArgumentEmpty{[Q]}{Empty}{Non empty}

\bigskip

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`\Q=3
\catcode`\T=3
\long\gdef\ifArgumentEmpty#1{%
  \long\def\@tempa##1##2Q##3##4##5T{##4}%
  \edef\@tempa{\@tempa#1QQ{\noexpand\@secondoftwo}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}T}%
  \@tempa
}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\textbf{Fixed definition}

Empty: \ifArgumentEmpty{}{Empty}{Non empty}

Spaces: \ifArgumentEmpty{ }{Empty}{Non empty}

ABC: \ifArgumentEmpty{ABC}{Empty}{Non empty}

Q: \ifArgumentEmpty{Q}{Empty}{Non empty}

[Q]: \ifArgumentEmpty{[Q]}{Empty}{Non empty}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in the `[Q]` line with the original definition the result is what I predicted: `Q` is typeset and then also `Empty` and `Non empty`. This also proves, if still not clear, that the `Q` in the parameter text of `\@tempa` doesn't have category code 3.

### Workarounds

File a bug report and do, until a fix is issued,

```
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`\Q=3
\catcode`\T=3
\long\gdef\ifArgumentEmpty#1{%      
  \long\def\@tempa##1##2Q##3##4##5T{##4}%
  \long\edef\@tempa{\@tempa#1QQ{\noexpand\@secondoftwo}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}T}%
  \@tempa
}
\endgroup
\makeatother
```

An easier workaround is to say

```
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\ifArgumentEmpty\ifblank
```

---

A possibly better fix to suggest to the package developer:

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`\Q=3
\catcode`\T=3
\long\gdef\ALGOCF@argemptyaux#1#2Q#3#4#5T{#4}
\long\gdef\ifArgumentEmpty#1{%
  \begingroup\long\edef\@tempa{\endgroup
    \ALGOCF@argemptyaux#1QQ{\noexpand\@secondoftwo}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}T%
  }\@tempa
}
\endgroup
\makeatother
```

The auxiliary macro is defined once for all, since it's going to always receive the same definition; with the

```
\begingroup\edef\@tempa{\endgroup...}\@tempa
```

trick, `\@tempa` is only set temporarily and doesn't pollute the hash memory. No global definition necessary.

Comment: The cavalry has arrived! `:)`

Comment: @Jubobs Just in time: Mrs. Mallory is praying, Hatfield has been killed a moment before killing her with his last bullet; Ringo Kid and the marshal don't have any more shells. Buck and Mr. Peacock are wounded, Dallas is keeping care of the baby and Mr. Gatewood does nothing. Doc Boone drinks. ;-)

Comment: Your detective work is worthy of a bounty. The root of the problem is definitely a recurring misunderstanding: so many TeX users  ([incl. I](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146062/trouble-defining-a-macro-that-typesets-underscore-characters-as)) misunderstand/overlook that "TeX absorbs tokens and catcode assignments are permanent"...

Comment: Alas, I'm not well versed in Western movies. I had to look up the *Stagecoach* reference... I might give it a shot (pun intended). A more recent one I can recommend is *True Grit* (2010).

Comment: @Jubobs Would you compare *True Grit* (2010) with the true *True Grit* (1969)? I definitely wouldn't (putting off my hat, because John Wayne has been evoked twice). `;-)`